# defaultAdapter in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table

when i try to construct a query to my db in my model like

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_Resume extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

protected $_name = 'users';

public function getFiveLastResume (){

   $select= $db->select()->from('users')->order("id DESC")->limit(5);
   $stmt = $db->query($select);
   $row = $stmt->fetchAll();       
   return $row;

   }
}
```

so i have an error `Notice: Undefined variable: db`

if I write adapter before query

```
   $db = Zend_Db::factory('PDO_MYSQL',array(
'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'dbname'   => 'sport'       
));
```

thats work good. why does my adapter not work ?

my application.ini contain right database config,cuz more simply queries work out good without  including adapter. im noob in zend, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$db` is undefined in the local scope which is why you get the error.

Since you are inside a `DbTable` object, you can use `$this` to get the DB adapter:

```
public function getFiveLastResume () {
    $select = $this->select()->from('users')->order("id DESC")->limit(5);
    $stmt   = $select->query();
    $row    = $stmt->fetchAll();       
    return $row;
}
```

Anywhere else in your application, you should be able to get a reference to the default DB adapter using:

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
$select = $db->select()->from('table')...;
```

This of course assumes you have created a `Zend_Db_Table` object and set it as the default adapter.

Comment: thanks for answering but i had an error message Fatal error: Call to undefined method Application_Model_DbTable_Resume::query() which i resolved when put $select into fetchAll() like fetchAll($select)

Comment: Thanks you are correct, it was wrong at first.  I updated the code to fix that error.  I think its different than your fix but both methods should be the same.